# Retrieving and parsing protein sequences from GenBank using Entrez in BioPython

Tags: python, parsing, biopython, fasta, protein-database

As will soon be obvious, I am new to Python and coding in general. I have a list of Gene IDs stored as a text file and I want to use the Entrez functions to search the GenBank database and retrieve the protein sequences corresponding to the IDs. Ideally I want the end product to be a FASTA file as I am really only interested in the sequence at this point. Using the Biopython tutorial (http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec15), I came up with this:

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO
Entrez.email = "me@mysite.com"
id_list = set(open('test.txt', 'rU'))
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="protein", id=id_list, rettype="fasta", retmode="text")   
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
    print ">" + seq_record.id, seq_record.description
print seq_record.seq
handle.close()
```

But when I run it, I get the error:

```
File "C:/Python27/Scripts/entrez_files.py", line 5, in <module>
  handle = Entrez.efetch(db="protein", id=id_list, rettype="fasta", retmode="text")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Bio\Entrez\__init__.py", line 145, in efetch
  if ids.count(",") >= 200:
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'count'
```

I get a similar error every time I use rettype = 'fasta'. When I use rettype = 'gb' I don't get this error, but I really want to end up with a fasta file. Does anybody have some suggestions? Thank you!

EDIT: 
sorry I neglected to include what the input file is like. In a perfect world the code would accept an input format like this:

```
gi|285016822|ref|YP_003374533.1|
gi|285018887|ref|YP_003376598.1|
gi|285016823|ref|YP_003374534.1|
gi|285016824|ref|YP_003374535.1| 
....
```

But I have also tried using a simplified version with only the Gene IDs (GIs) like this:

```
285016822 
285018887 
285016823
285016824...
```

Comment: What does test.txt look like? Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Protip: there is also a Q&A site like stackoverflow for bioinformatics related questions: http://www.biostars.org

Comment: I updated the post to include the input format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [efetch's source code](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Entrez-pysrc.html#efetch), the `id` parameter must have a `count` method. Usually this will be a string with a single ID or a Python list with all the IDs. You are using a `set`, presumably to eliminate repeated values, so you can convert to a list like this:

```
id_list = set(open('test.txt', 'rU'))
id_list = list(id_list)
```